# how to get SelectList from another Ienumerable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

Ihave `IEnumerable` named (JournalArticleTypes ) the elements inside this `IEnumerable` will help me to access some records of a table named (articletypes) the condition is that when the foreign key (ArticleTypeId) of any element of `IEnumerable` is being equal to any Id of any record from the table (articletypes) then i will save the record that have this Id in a new `SelectList` named (articletypes )...so i will use first `IEnumerable`to get select list from specifc table(articletypes)...how to do it?

I tried by using this wrong code

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public JsonResult GetArticleType(int journalid)
{
    var JournalArticleTypes = _context.JournalArticleTypes.Where(u => u.JournalId == journalid);
    foreach(var item in JournalArticleTypes)
    {
        var articletypes = new SelectList(_context.ArticleTypes.Where(u => u.Id == item.ArticleTypeId), "Id", "Name");

    }
    return Json(articletypes);
}
```

Ajax code:

```
<script>
    $("#joartcltypeid").empty();

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#jornlid").change(function () {
            $("#joartcltypeid").empty();
            $("#joartcltypeid").append($('<option>', { text: "@Localizer["إختر نوع المقالة"]" }));
            if ($("#jornlid").val() > 0) {
                var JournalOptions = {};
                JournalOptions.url = "/@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name/JournalRepositories/GetArticleType/";
                JournalOptions.data = { journalid: $("#jornlid").val() };
                JournalOptions.success = function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                        $("#joartcltypeid").append($('<option>', { value: row.value, text: row.text }))
                    });
                };
                JournalOptions.error = function () { alert("@Localizer["UniError"]"); };
                $.ajax(JournalOptions);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: sorry i added the wrong text ....now i edited it

Comment: I'm confused, are you trying to return Json or SelectList?

Comment: i want to return select list using json

Comment: i will add ajax code above to make it more easy for you

Comment: http://learninfinity.info/cascading-dropdown-list-using-json-data/ is this what you need? Click the "Demo"

Comment: or this one on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XVbRcLAmK4U

Comment: ok i will see it ....thanx

Comment: I tried to optimize the formatting and the description of the main issue, but I could not really get what you are trying to achieve. Please edit the question and give a better description of your problem and of your goal. The structure of the description in the first couple of lines is not clear and ambiguous.

Comment: ok mohammed ...i will do and tell you by a comment

Comment: Mohammed Noureldin ...i edited the post can you see it and tell me if the question still ambiguous